# In Google Group Admin-SDK how do I get the "code" parameter?

Tags: php, curl, google-admin-sdk

Simple question I am sure.  But I am new to the Google Group Admin-SDK and I want to authenticate using php and CURL:

```
$oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$clienttoken_post = array(
"code" => $code,
"client_id" => $client_id,
"client_secret" => $client_secret,
"redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
"grant_type" => "authorization_code"
);

$curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$authObj = json_decode($json_response);
```

Most of this I understand, except I can't figure out where the value of the parameter "code" comes from.  I hope someone can help me understand how I can get a valid "code" for this application.

BTW I don't want to use a code library in this situation, just php and CURL similar to the above.

Thanks

TimS